# Core Plot 1.0 my touch annotations won't work

Tags: ios, annotations, core-plot

I have been working on this for a couple of days and am quite stumped.  I am trying to make a graph in core plot that allows the user to push on a data point and get the coordinates.  I made a sample App that just makes a linear graph.  My problem is that I can not get the touch feature to work.  I referenced many of the plots on the core plot website, but I just can't get it to work in my App.  Here is what I did;

In my header I made a property CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *annotation.  I also used, interface ViewController : UIViewController .

In my implementation I synthesized annotation.  In my ViewDidAppear method I made a data array with CGPointMake.

```
NSMutableArray *linearstuff = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
{
    float y = (b * (l)) + c;
    [linearstuff addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(l, y)]];
    l = l + inc;
}

self.data = linearstuff;
[self initPlot];
```

My method initPlot configures the graph and has a couple of configure methods.  So in a method I called configurePlots I alloc and init a CPTScatterPlot called linearGraph.  I used linearGraph.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection in that method as well.  And then for the plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex, I did the following.

```
- (void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
NSLog(@"touch");
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

if (_annotation)
{
    [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:_annotation];
    _annotation = nil;
}

CPTMutableTextStyle *annotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
annotationTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
annotationTextStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
annotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";

NSValue *value = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
NSString *number1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", point.x];
NSString *number2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", point.y];

NSLog(@"x and y are, %.2f, %.2f", point.x, point.y);
NSLog(@"number1 and number2 are, %.2f, %.2f", point.x, point.y);

NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.x];
NSNumber *y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.y];

NSArray *anchorPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: x, y, nil];

NSString *final = [number1 stringByAppendingString:number2];
NSLog(@"final is %@",final);


CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:final style:annotationTextStyle];
_annotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
_annotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
_annotation.displacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
[graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:_annotation];
}
```

I tried to follow what I saw on the core plot website.  I took my array and got the index.  I placed those values in an NSNumber to make a string for the annotation.  However, it does not come up on the graph.  Does any one know what I did incorrect?  Any insight would be much appreciated.  I have read many of the core plot questions here on SO, but can't find something that would help in my situation.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that the `anchorPoint` and label text are what you expect? I'm assuming that the plot area has a non-white fill. :-)

Comment: @Eric Skroch,  Yes!, the plot has no theme so my blue background comes through.  As for verification, I have tried to NSLog things, but they don't show up.  The NSLog I have in the code so far, "touch" never appears.  Do you think this means it never gets called?  I did NSLog the method on one of your examples and it did not come up either.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You should see the log messages—several of the examples do that and it works fine. What are you using for `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection`? Try a fairly large value just to see if you can get it working.

Comment: @Eric Skroch,  I am currently using 25.0f for the hit detection.  I will try something bigger and try to NSLog the anchor point again.  Do you think I set up something wrong?  Does my code look OK?  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Eric Skroch, I tried NSLog on some of your demos and yes it did work.  I was looking at the wrong window in the Debug area!  But my NSLog in the plotSymbolWasSelected... still doesn't make it into the Debug area.  Any ideas why it might not.  Thanks again.

Comment: @EricSkroch, Sorry to keep bugging you.  But I wanted to ask if I set up the .h file correctly.  After the interface ViewController : UIViewController, I put in CPTScatterPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate. Is this correct? Because my plotSymbolWasSelected.. methods still is not being called.  Thanks.

Comment: The class definition looks ok. Is your view controller set as the plot delegate?

Comment: @EricSkroch, in my header file I have used CPTPlotSpaceDelegate.  I also have the two scatter plot's data source and delegate.  as mentioned above.  I am going to start out new and try again with one of your demos, simple scatter plot, that has the plotSymbol.. Method in it and try to make it work for my app.  Thanks again for all your help, if you think of anything more let me know!

Comment: Each plot has both `dataSource` and `delegate` properties. These can be the same controller or different ones. The hit-detection method is sent to the delegate. Be sure it's set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what do you mean to set it properly?  I used the method on the linearGraph that I alloced in the configure plots method.  But I bet that is the reason, I have been trying all day again to get something to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone following this.  I first want to thank Eric Skroch for all his help, AGAIN!!!!  But I finally found what I was doing wrong.  I had made the viewController the plot delegate, however, I did not say so when I was making the plot.  I added linearGraph.delegate = self; and now the plotSymbol... method is called!  Thanks @Eric Skroch.

Comment: I also had to change my plotSymbolWas.... method.  See my original post to see the updated code.

Comment: @Spynet, I am glad it helped you out!